# Different result with Java TransportClient than REST/CURL

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have written a whole query with aggregations and such which gives me exactly what I want when I use REST and call with CURL and do a POST:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:9200/user_index/account_record/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs":{
      "updates_by_user":{
         "terms":{
            "script":"doc['accountNumber'].value"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to use this same JSON and get the same result back from the Java API.   Instead the Java API behaves as if I have done a HTTP GET operation.   Is there a way to easily reuse the same JSON through the Java API?   It looks from the Javadoc like one must break this up into pieces with numerous methods like .addAggregation.   I just get a high level count back and no detail on buckets

For the record, my JSON is a lot more complicated, I am just simplifying for sake of the question.

My Java code looks like

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("user_index")
                .setTypes("account_record")
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setSize(0)
                .setQuery(query)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

Any ideas?   I guess I can always use HTTP Client but would rather not pull in another library/syntax unless it is necessary.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            .prepareSearch("user_index")
            .setTypes("account_record")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
            .setSize(0)
            .addAggregation(
                    AggregationBuilders.terms("updates_by_user")
                    .script(new Script("doc['accountNumber'].value"))
            )
            .execute().actionGet();
```

And then you need something like this to access the aggregation results:

```
Terms terms = response.getAggregations().get("updates_by_user");
```